# Boolean input flipping

Tags: php

I'm getting really strange results on a php script that takes boolean input. The idea is that the data needs to be stored as either a 1 or a 0, but the input to the php script is a string in true/false format. Check this out:

```
<?php
    function boolToBinary($str) {
        echo $_POST['wants_sms'] . " " . $str;
        die();

        // posting this so that you can see what this function is supposed to do
        //    once it is debugged
        if ($str == true) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    $gets_sms = boolToBinary($_POST['wants_sms']);
```

Here is the output from this function:

```
false true
```

How can that be??? Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: Solution: Still not sure why my output was flipped, but the fundamental problem is solved like this:

```
if ($str === 'true') {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to RocketHazmat for this.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_POST['wants_sms']);` anywhere in your script?

Comment: If the input is a string, why are you checking as if it is an actual bool. Is it a bool or not?

Comment: POST values are always string.  `$_POST['wants_sms']` will *never* be a boolean.  Chances are `$_POST['wants_sms']` is the string `"true"`.  Try this `return $bool === 'true' ? 1 : 0;`.

Comment: Even though the OP needs to correct the `if` statement, since input values are indeed all strings, he is killing the script after echoing the values before the check. Very odd.

Comment: @Asok Nothing odd about that, he's just debugging the script. He's showing us the values before the `die`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing @Asok.  His function would definitely not work, but the output is very odd since there is no typecasting (`$_POST` is a string and is echoed twice).

Comment: @meagar The odd behavior I am referring to is that the input value and the passed parameter should be the same.

Comment: I sincerely doubt the code you've posted could produce the output you're showing us. All you've done is (in a round-about way) this: `echo $_POST['wants_sms'] . " " . $_POST['wants_sms']`; there really isn't any way this could output `false true`.

Comment: @Asok Ah, yes, that part I agree with. There doesn't seem to be any way the code posted could produce that result.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - that solved it. Will you please post that as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @usr55410 If that fixed your issue, you really *didn't* post a valid question here. The code you've posted could not be fixed by using `===` instead of `==`. After your edit, it's even more impossible for the code you're posting to be giving you the output you're claiming it does. If the code you're posting isn't going to recreate the issue you claim to experiencing, you shouldn't post it at all, it's only hurting our ability to help you.

Comment: @meagar. I'm sorry if you think that i wasted your time. I've been accused here of not seeing the output that is on my screen, not posting my code correctly, blah, blah, blah. I appreciate your help. I really do. All I know is that of all the accusations that I got on this post, the only thing that solved it was what was posted by RocketHazmat. I'm sorry if that bothers you.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

see this example:

`var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)`

And the explanations:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>   ...
>   the empty string, and the string "0"
>   ...
>   Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

In your case the  `$_POST['wants_sms']` variable contains a string `"false"`;

Comment: But the weird thing is he never typecasts it.  He passes `_POST['want_sms']` (which `= 'false'`), and then echoes the variable `true` before any typecast to a bool.

Comment: Yes I see. But the described output's most probable cause can be that he converted somewhere to bool. And he forgot to mention this in the example.

Comment: I would assume instead that he's just done a bad job copying his code into stack overflow.

Comment: If he didn't see the `"false true"` then probably he wouldn't post here. I hope...